Shakespeare and his syntax: "we hunt not, we"
Titus Andronicus, act II, scene II

Chiron, we hunt not, we, with horse  nor hound, But hope to pluck a dainty doe to ground.

Context:
Chiron is a character's name. It's his brother addressing him, proposing some wrongdoing. But meaning is not important, though.
Question:
What's the syntax role of the second "we"? If it's a noun phrase then where is its predicate?

It's just standard repetition for emphasis, as in I'm British, me. See Is it natural to say "Me, I xyz"?

It's there mainly to complete the pentameter

@AndyBonner: Shakespeare was not so shoddy! He could have completed it with "we hunt not, nor with horse nor hound"; or "we hunt not so, with horse nor hound"; or... In other words, that second "we" is there for a purpose.

My first thought was that the second we was actually the subject of a paratactic second sentence which was equivalent to "We do not hunt. We, with horse nor hound, but hope to pluck a dainty doe […]". But to be honest, I don't know enough about EModE syntax to assess whether that's even a possible interpretation.

@Schmuddi I had that exact same response. How can we be so sure the second we belongs to the first idea when it fits so naturally with the second? Isn't this just two sentences run together for poetic license?

@Schmuddi Guess I should've read the comments before answering...

The question raises another question:  why it is that we use 'me' ,'her'; 'him' after "it is"...  Why is it that when someone asks who broke some window, the culprit declares "It was me" and not "it was I", which now sounds weird, as does "it was "he" or "it was she".  there is something funny about personal pronouns.

This structure is called lone pronoun tag sometimes shortened as ProTag.
This 2021 paper on Lone Pronoun Tags by Louise Mycock and James Misson says that this structure has not been researched very thoroughly:

Lone pronoun tag (ProTag) constructions have received relatively little attention despite being present in corpora of Present Day British English (PDBE).

It’s terrible, that. He likes me, him.


According to this paper, this structure is often used by Shakespeare, but not only by him:

Lone pronoun tag constructions are also found in Early Modern English (EModE). Visser (1963: 56) states that they appear “with striking frequency in the dramatic works of Ben Jonson, Shakespeare and contemporaries”.

This may have credit and chimes reason, this! (Jonson: The New Inn, 1631) 
Chiron, we hunt not, we, with horse nor hound (Shakespeare: Titus Andronicus, 1588)


This article quotes Partridge 1953: 29; (see also Schlauch 1959: 99), who say that this structure is

a pleonastic pronominal … repeated at the end of the sentence for the sake of emphasis.

It is also considered

as a means by which ‘the subject pronoun gets special emphasis by its being repeated in the same form at the end of the utterance’ (Visser 1963: 56)

The article is quite detailed, if you read on I am sure you will find all your answers there.

In works with metre, like Shakespeare's and probably others', it provides a useful additional stressed syllable.

A quick search in Google books found "He's a funny  guy, that one." in a 2022 novel.

There may be some overlap with the emphasis role of cleft sentences: They're very good, these cookies.

“Lone pronoun tag” (or “ProTag”) is not a thing; it’s a coinage by a particular scholar writing about right dislocation in Early Modern English.

To be honest, my first thought to the French repetition of the subject pronoun as in Je ne sais pas, moi. But that's beside the point :)

@Tinfoil Hat is right; this is a subset of right dislocation (with the repeated subject pronominal here).

Wouldn't it need to be "We hunt not, us" then?

@Ivo "We hunt not, us" would be more informal than "We hunt not, we", since the pronoun repeated is the subject and should be in the nominative case when repeated.

@fev - as inherited by bayou Cajun - "I like that one, me" "He took that, him"

@Ivo — fev is incorrect — nothing to do with formality. From the paper cited: “The most obvious difference between ProTags in [Early Modern English] and [present-day British English] relates to case... In [Early Modern English], the default form of the pronoun is the subjective/nominative rather than the objective/accusative as it is in [present-day British English]...”


Chiron, we hunt not, we, with horse nor hound,

is right dislocation.
Compare Rossitten's answer in "Knows an awful lot about the Dark Arts, Snape"
And then you should read John Lawler's comment.
For more details, see Right dislocation in Northern England: frequency and use — perception meets reality (PDF) by Mercedes Durham, University of Aberdeen.
That paper has the following caveat:

Right dislocation is referred to by a multitude of other names,
both in dialectological and syntactic literature. Quirk et al . (1985) use the term
amplificatory tags, Petyt (1985) examines emphatic tags, Melchers (1983) deals
with tag statements, Wright (1909) and Visser (1963) classify it as subject
repetition. Finally, in the field of literature on focus, they are sometimes called
tails (see Aijmer Timmis 2009). The numerous names given to this
construction of course complicate attempts to compare studies to one another.


It belongs to the second part of the sentence: We, with horse nor hound, but hope to pluck a dainty doe to ground.
"We" is the subject that goes with the verb "hope".
It can be a little confusing that the verse structure doesn't align with the the sentence structure at this point, and then there's the parenthetical phrase in the way, obscuring it a little more, and finally the capital letter (signifying not a new sentence but a new line of verse) can throw you off too.
The whole sentence could be more distinctly repunctuated:
Chiron, we hunt not - we (with horse nor hound) but hope to pluck a dainty doe to ground.
(If you wonder about the word "but", here it's a synonym of "only". These days it's kind of an archaic use. As is "we hunt not": today one would say "we don't hunt".)

Very good. I find that when I find this kind of thing and others jump on other somewhat misguided answers, I end up losing out. It's happened quite a few times to me around here. +1

This is nonsense. But means yet here. Chiron, we don’t hunt with horses or dogs—yet hope to catch a dainty doe, nonetheless.

I'm uncertain as to whether you've gotten an answer that satisfied your question but...
If you remove from the equation - "with horse nor hound"
He was saying - "We hunt not, we but hope to pluck a dainty doe to ground".
In modern vernacular it would equate to - "We aren't hunting. But we intend to catch a doe without the help of a horse or dog".

You do if you have a bow-and-arrow at your disposal. I never actually read Shakespeare for myself so I don't really know what the context surrounding the passage is. Just my initial thoughts though.

In this word order, "but" isn't a conjunction with the meaning "though, however, despite that". It's an adverb with the meaning "only, merely, simply". Compare the lyrics of Row Your Boat: "life is but a dream".

How is this different from @Divizna's answer?
